# Setting up Cgroups

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I have some go code that creates a skeleton root system and then under every linux namespace chroots into it, setups up cgroups and then runs a process inside of that cgroup/chroot.

I have gotten most of it to work but I am having trouble getting the cgroups to work.

I have been following [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) for the majority of my work with cgroups and I am still super new to them as a concept.

If I manually create this environment and run the following commands everything seems to work fine.
(I have added numbers to these for reference later)

```
1) mount -t proc proc /proc
2) mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
3) mount -t tmpfs cgroup_root /sys/fs/cgroup
4) mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
5) mount -t cgroup pids -o pids /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
```

As you can see from the output of cat /proc/mounts

```
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
cgroup_root /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
pids /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,relatime,pids 0 0
```

I have a mounted `/proc, /sys, /sys/fs/cgroup`, and a pids cgroup at `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids`. I can now setup this pids cgroup with any settings I want and everything works fine.

My problem is I am trying to do the same thing In Go and I am having issues.

In my code I can successfully execute up to step 4) `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/pids` and I have even verified that this file gets created but I am having trouble getting syscall.Mount() to do what I want for the 5th command.

Here is what I have right now.

```
func mountPid(pidsLoc string) {
    fstype := "cgroup"
    source := "pids"
    flags := uintptr(0)
    data := "pids"

    err := syscall.Mount(source, pidsLoc, fstype, flags, data)
    if err != nil {
        serverFatal(err)
    }
}
```

Where `pidsLoc = /sys/fs/cgroup/pids`, but when I try and run this I get an error "operation not permitted".

I really don't think this is a permissions error though because I was able to mount my `/sys`, `/proc` and `/sys/fs/cgroups` just fine. Here is the code I used for those three:

```
func mountProc() {
    source := "proc"
    fstype := "proc"
    target := "/proc"
    flags := uintptr(0)
    data := ""

    err := syscall.Mount(source, target, fstype, flags, data)
    if err != nil {
        serverFatal(err)
    }
}

func mountSys() {
    source := "sysfs"
    fstype := "sysfs"
    target := "/sys"
    flags := uintptr(0)
    data := ""

    err := syscall.Mount(source, target, fstype, flags, data)
    if err != nil {
        serverFatal(err)
    }
}

//This can not be called before mountSys()
func mountCGroupFS() {
    fstype := "tmpfs"
    source := "cgroup_root"
    target := "/sys/fs/cgroup"
    flags := uintptr(0)
    data := ""

    err := syscall.Mount(source, target, fstype, flags, data)
    if err != nil {
        serverFatal(err)
    }
}
```

And I ran all of those with the same permissions as before. Maybe I am just using syscall.Mount() wrong but I am not sure. The documentation for the syscall package in Go is not very good and I have found I mostly have to read the C/C++ documentation for the methods that syscall is wrapping and then trying to make connections between the two.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. [Here](https://github.com/lkelly93/executable) is a link to the repo if you are interested. I am trying to make a program that allows you to execute foreign code "safely".

Comment: Why not use this: https://github.com/containerd/cgroups?

Comment: I did not know about that and it looks like it will be a great resource but I am trying to build my own from scratch to learn so I don't want to use another library.